# Trouble with threads in a function to exec another function after X time

Tags: c++, multithreading, time, pthreads, pseudocode

I am trying to create this function in order to exec another function after X time:

```
void            execAfter(double time, void *(*func)(void *), t_params *params);
```

I have made an Thread encapsulation and a Time encapsulation (objects Thread and Time).

What I want to do in pseudo code:

```
Call execAfter
  instantiate Thread
  call thread->create(*funcToExec, *params, timeToWait)
[inside thread, leaving execAfter]
  instanciate Time object
  wait for X time
  exec funcToExec
  delete Time object
[leaving thread, back to execAfter]
  delete Thread object              <---- probleme is here, see description below.
  return ;
```

How can I delete my Thread object properly, without blocking the rest of the execution nor taking the risk to delete it before required time has elapsed.

I am quite lost, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), you could do it something like this:

```
void execAfter(const int millisecs, std::function<void(void*)> func, void* param)
{
    std::thread thread([=](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(millisecs));
        func(param);
    });

    // Make the new thread "detached" from the parent thread
    thread.detach();
}
```

The "magic" that you are looking for is the [`detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) call.

Comment: Wont this block the main execution of the program?

Comment: @Mayerz No, it "detaches" the new thread to run completely independent of the creating thread. You don't even have to join the thread (nor should you).

Comment: Ok so after calling your code, all memory will be freed automatically?

Comment: @Mayerz All memory regarding the thread itself anyway. Any memory you allocate _in_ the thread you have to free yourself of course.

Comment: Ok for your previous response.
I am still a but confused by your syntax, "[=]()".
It works, but i dont understand the [=] thing :).

Comment: @Mayerz It's part of the lambda capture, and means "capture everything by value".

Comment: Ok thanks for edit, it's a new feature for me, I am gonna check it.
Thanks for the effective and fast answer!