# Use a templated function outside of the .cpp file without declaring it in the .hh file

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, compilation

*The title isn't representative of my question but I couldn't find a correct one, feel free to edit.*

#### Context :

Bomberman project for school.

In my `Bomberman` I have an `execAfter()` function prototyped as follow:

```
void execAfter(std::function<void(t_params *)> func, t_params *params, int ms);
```

The aim of this function is to execute `func`, taking `params` struct as parameter, after a `ms` delay.

Example : *drop a bomb, explose after X ms*.

It works perfectly (using lambda as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563739/trouble-with-threads-in-a-function-to-exec-another-function-after-x-time) on a previous SO question).

#### Problem

Now I want to template my function in order to be able to pass different function type and different `params` type.

Time.hh

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
void execAfter(T func, U params, V ms);
```

Time.cpp

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
void Time::execAfter(T func, U params, V ms)
{ 
 ...
}
```

(templating the `V` param is useless but it was just for compilation problem, I will figure out how to do later)

Example : *call the function `void X(Y)`, passing as parameter `Y*`.

I done everything the right way, from my point of view, everything compile, except after linkage gcc throws this:

```
[...]
 linkage ...
[...]
 src/Entities/Character.o: In function `Character::landBomb()':
 /home/teube_a/Code/tech2/c++/bomberman-2016-      couille_c/zizi_g/src/Entities/Character.cpp:208: undefined reference to `void   Time::execAfter<std::function<void (s_params*)>, s_params*, int>(std::function<void  (s_params*)>, s_params*, int)'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make: *** [bomberman] Error 1
```

I really don't understand, please explain me the possibles reasons why this templated function can't be generated.

Tell me if you need more info.

Comment: And implementation of your function is included too?

Comment: @soon you want execAfter() function's code?

Comment: Are you sure your template body is in header file? BTW, you'd probably like to ready about perfect forwarding (e.g. http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_07.html ).

Comment: No. I'm talking about it: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). Do you know about it?

Comment: @soon Maybe a good idea, but I dont think it will save me right now.

Comment: Tell me only one thing: do you have `Time.cpp` included? Or you compile it separately and then link?

Comment: @soon Inside Time.cpp I include Time.hh. Nothing else, is this a problem?

Comment: Yes. Implementation of templates should be included. Please, read the link posted above again.

Comment: Will do, thanks for not giving up and help me even I told you this wasn't the problem.

Comment: No problems. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ a Template is understood as a Template for the Compiler to generate code. So the Compiler has to know at every instantiation of the template, what the implementation is, i.e. it should to be in the header file the Template is defined in.

You can have concrete Implementations for templates like that:

```
template <typename T>
T f(T) { ...}

template<> 
int f<int>(int) {...}
```

then the linker will find an implementation to a concrete type, and will use it preferred to the compiler generated version.

What you have now is a template declaration without the implementation, wich means the linker will search only for the concrete Implementation, and does not find one!

There are two possible solutions:

1. You provide a default template Implementation instead of only the signature
2. You provide a concretisation of the template for the requested type. Keep in mind, that you have to/are able to do this for every type your template should work on.

Comment: Well I have done others templated functions the same way and they perfectly works, do you think this can be an exception?

Comment: Maybe you used the other templated functions only in the cpp files where they where defined, below the definition?

Comment: Hum interesting, I check this and come back at you soon.

Comment: Ok this was the problem. You can do it my way only when you use it inside the same .cpp file. Thanks a lot.